# Notation of remainder for a series expansion

Tags: notation

I am writing something and met a notational conflicting. Is there any alternative notation for the remainder for a series, e.g. Taylor, expansion? It is typically denoted as R, but is there anything else and used before (I don't want to invent my own notation unless necessary)?

Any suggestion with reference is greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much in advance 
Ethan

Comment: I've seen $\Delta f_N$ used to denote the remainder.  For example, $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n x^n + \Delta f_N(x).$$  Whatever you choose, you can make a little note about what the symbol means to avoid confusing the reader.

Comment: I've seen it denoted by $r_n(x)$, as well as directly by the integral estimate.

Comment: Great!!!! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: > Antonio Vargas Thank you so much for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html), both of which use $R_N$ (or other subscript) to denote the remainder. In my experience, this is the most common.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know $R$ is the most common one, but there is a lot of $R$ denotes to something else in my essay. That's also common in other convention...